# How to generate increment number for each group of data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

This is my table data

```
prod_id category_id
 1      1       
 2      2       
 3      2       
 4      3       
 5      3       
 6      3
```

Expected result

```
prod_id category_id seq_no
 1      1           1 
 2      2           1
 3      2           2
 4      3           1
 5      3           2
 6      3           3
```

This is just one of the sample to generate sequence number based on category, it might be other condition as well.

I am trying to generate sequence number for each group of data i get based on id_category field. I tried dense_rank() method but it is not supported for MySQL.

How can i generate sequence number for each group in this way?

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id_category) As seq_no
```

My query

```
Product::leftJoin('category','category.id_category','=','product.id_category')
........
->get();
```

Comment: A quick google of mysql dense rank is in order.

Comment: Or just upgrade to mysql v8.0

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have huge amounts of data, it's probably easiest to

- grab everything
- group by category
- sort each category by product
- loop through each category and set the sequence number based on the current index

While I don't know the exact nature of your tables, it would look something like this, with your query as the start:

```
Product::leftJoin('category','category.id_category','=','product.id_category')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('category_id')
    ->each(function ($group) {
        $group->sortBy('product_id')
            ->map(function ($product, $index) {
                    $product->seq_no = $index + 1;
            });
    });
```

Though note that this should be treated as pseudocode and adapted as fits your application best.